# A div tag is shown but not hidden even after giving hide() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#total1").show();
  });

  $(".nstSlider1").on('click', function() {
   $("#total1").show();
   $("#total2, , #total4, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider2").on('click', function() {
   $("#total2").show();
   $("#total4, , #total1, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider3").on('click', function() {
   $("#total3").show();
   $("#total2, , #total1, #total4").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider4").on('click', function() {
   $("#total4").show();
   $("#total2, #total1, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });
</script>
```

When i click on .nstSlider1, it shows `#total1` and hide other `#total2`, `#total3`, `#total4`...but when i click on `.nstSlider2`, it also shows `#total2`, but does not hide #total1...hence when i click on `.nstSlider3`, `#total3` was shown, but others are again not hided...why?any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Look your comma `$("#total2, , #total4, #total3")`

Comment: where is the code to hide them?

Comment: All of the `.on()` functions should be inside of the document ready function wrapper, unless the `<script>` tag is at the bottom of your page, then you don't need any document ready wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is a Syntax error in every click handler:

```
#total2, , #total4
```

Double commata is not needed here I guess.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery function show() you can also use hide()

Try using **hide()** instead of **css('display', 'none')**

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#total1").show();
    $("#total2,#total4, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider1").on('click', function() {
   $("#total1").show();
   $("#total2,#total4, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider2").on('click', function() {
   $("#total2").show();
   $("#total4,#total1, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider3").on('click', function() {
   $("#total3").show();
   $("#total2,#total1, #total4").css('display', 'none');
  });

  $(".nstSlider4").on('click', function() {
   $("#total4").show();
   $("#total2, #total1, #total3").css('display', 'none');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="total1">total1</div>
<div id="total2">total2</div>
<div id="total3">total3</div>
<div id="total4">total4</div>


<div class="nstSlider1">nstSlider1</div>
<div class="nstSlider2">nstSlider2</div>
<div class="nstSlider3">nstSlider3</div>
<div class="nstSlider4">nstSlider4</div>
```